# IIS set conditional header in case of cache hit

Tags: iis, cache

**Question**: With IIS, I am looking solution to add a custom header in case of a cache-hit. Although I do not find any possibility to access cache-hits in the web.config. What should be added to the web.config to add this behavior? Is it possible at all?

**Goal:**
For "debugging and automated-logging-rules"-reasons I want to set a custom-header "X-Cache"= "HIT" / "MISS" in case of a cache hit in IIS.

The result should look like this (Sample is taken form an other project running with Varnish):

[image: google inspection screenshot of X-Cache]

**So far** I was working with Varnish where this is very easy to achieve by adding:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
  # Called before a cached object is delivered to the client.

  # Add debug header to see if it's a HIT/MISS and the number of hits, disable when not needed
  if (obj.hits > 0) { 
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }
  
  .
  .
  .
  
  return (deliver);
}
```

**What I tried:**

```
  <location path="/windows/something/caching-folder">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="X-Cache" value="HIT" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

In this solution I do not get the "MISS" response and it is not working for hits. Although it adds the Header.

Comment: Welcome. What is the business-related question or issue in this? What are you trying to solve here?

Comment: The question is: How do I check for a cache-hit in IIS server, so I can add a custom header in case of hit and in case of miss.

Comment: Please always improve your own question by editing, instead of posting it to the commentary section. After a while, it might be overseen. In addition, i took some research for you as you seems none to be done. if you want to verify that kind as i been could find, there is no native function and need to be written on your own

Comment: Web servers don't have feature parity, so no surprise you can do something with Varnish but not with IIS. Usually people need to write their own IIS modules.

Comment: You can't influence the cache hit in IIS using the web.config